# How to animate ToggleButton background color in WPF (xaml)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I would like to dynamically change background color of `ToggleButton` depending on it's state. Here's my XAML code:

```xml
<ToggleButton
    Width="286"
    Height="50"
    x:Name="HistoryToggle"
    IsChecked="{Binding HistoryMode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsEnabled="True">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Grid
                            x:Name="outerGrid">
                            <Border
                                x:Name="HistoryToggleBorder"                         
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                CornerRadius="4"
                                Background="#1E3555">
                                <TextBlock
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    FontSize="20"
                                    FontWeight="Regular"
                                    Foreground="White"
                                    Text="MyToggle" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <EventTrigger 
                                RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation

                                            Storyboard.TargetName="HistoryToggleBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            From="#1E3555"
                                            To="#009ABE"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.15"
                                            FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>

                            <EventTrigger 
                                RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation

                                            Storyboard.TargetName="HistoryToggleBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            From="#009ABE"
                                            To="#1E3555"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.15"
                                            FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

When the application tries to open window containing my `ToggleButton` an exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Name „HistoryToggleBorder” cannot
>   be found in namespace „System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate”.'

and the application crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This XAML works fine when I paste it alone in a window. Can you try to clean your solution and rebuild all? Does it also work for you when you use your button alone in a brand new empty project?

Comment: I tried to clean it, rebuild but still it's not working properly. I also tried to change line "Storyboard.TargetName="HistoryToggleBorder"" and replace it with "Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=HistoryToggleBorder}"". Now the application gives an output "System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'ColorAnimation' (HashCode=21768161); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')", but it does not crash.

Comment: Can you try to create a new empty WPF project and paste your toggle button in there. It worked for me.

Comment: It works fine in empty WPF project. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Then we can't help unless you provide additional context. Try to remove stuff from your existing window until the problem disappears and update your question when you have a better understanding of your issue.

Comment: Have you tried to bind your IsChecked property in clean WPF project? I've noticed the problem must be connected to the binding. I've put breakpoint on HistoryMode property. It return value once and then programme crashes. Maybe the target of an animation is not created yet, when the value is returned? With no binding everything works correctly. Best regards